# How do I move all my apps, and my Apple ID to another iPod that has already been used?

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id

Ok, so my iPod Touch (its the 4th generation) is totally destroyed; a cracked screen and the screen is messed up, so I cant see anything. And my mom sad I can have hers, and she has a 4th generation like me. What I'm wondering is that if there is some way that I can switch all my apps and my ID to her iPod she gave to me, and I can get rid of her account, or at least take it off..? If anyone knows how I would REALLY appreciate it if you told me.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to do a restore, when the ipod touch boots back up do a restore from iTunes and enter your appleID and you're good to go.

Back up her ipod touch to her iTunes though she'll miss having one in a few weeks and probably end up buying one again :).